# Spring boot REST API Streaming large file download from a Server using WebClient and DataBufferUtils

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, streaming, spring-webclient

I'm writing a API from a Rest controller to download large file from a server without overloading the memory. For that, i'm trying to download streaming the file.

For now, i have use WebClient to send the GET request then, write the response on the HttpServletResponse

Here is my API code

```
@GetMapping(value = "/download/streaming/{fileId}", produces = { "application/pdf", "application/json" })
public void downloadDocumentStreaming(@Parameter(name = "fileId") @PathVariable("fileId") String fileId,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = //Some http header
        httpHeaders.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

        Flux<DataBuffer> flux = WebClient.create().get()
                .uri(builder -> builder.host(serverHostUrl).port(serverPort).scheme("https")
                        .path("/dowload/file/{fileId}").build(fileId))
                .headers(headers -> headers.addAll(httpHeaders)).retrieve().bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

        DataBufferUtils.write(flux, response.getOutputStream()).share().blockLast();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To test if my API is not overloading the memory, I run the application with the following VM argument: -Xmx64m

The download is working for file less than 64 MB
But for biggest file (example: 74 MB file), I'm getting the following error while testing from Postman.

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot reserve 4194304 bytes of direct buffer memory (allocated: 63010883, limit: 67108864)
at java.base/java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:178) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:121) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:332) ~[na:na]
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:701) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:676) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:215) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.tcacheAllocateNormal(PoolArena.java:197) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:139) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:129) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:396) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:188) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:179) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:140) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator$MaxMessageHandle.allocate(DefaultMaxMessagesRecvByteBufAllocator.java:120) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:150) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.87.Final.jar:4.1.87.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

It seems the streaming is not really working as the memory is getting overloaded.
In the other hand, I have another issue with swagger Ui. Even for small file size, swagger Ui is not able to render the response and is throwing the error ***Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text***.
[image]

I will really be happy if someone can have a workaround to sole the issue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you downloaded the large file from non-blocking server. Then we can use `StreamingResponseBody` to write directly to an OutputStream before passing that written information back to the client using a ResponseEntity. Your method will look like this

```
@GetMapping(value = "/download/streaming/{fileId}", produces = { "application/pdf", "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadDocumentStreaming(@Parameter(name = "fileId") @PathVariable("fileId") String fileId) {

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = //Some http header
        httpHeaders.setAccept(List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));

    Flux<DataBuffer> flux = WebClient.create().get()
            .uri(builder -> builder.host(serverHostUrl).port(serverPort).scheme("https")
                    .path("/dowload/file/{fileId}").build(fileId))
            .headers(headers -> headers.addAll(httpHeaders)).retrieve().bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);

    StreamingResponseBody stream = outputStream -> Mono.create(sink ->
            DataBufferUtils.write(flux, outputStream).subscribe(DataBufferUtils::release,
                sink::error,
                sink::success))
        .block();

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename="+"yourfilename.pdf")
        .body(stream);
}
```

Note that, if you're using Postman for testing then you need to set up the Max response in Postman as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot @phuongnq 1995 for your answer. I have tested the solution from postman and it works well. But I needed to set the timeout as followed spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=-1. Otherwise, I was getting AsyncRequestTimeoutException for big file.
Comming to swagguerUI, 
- For small files, the download is still showing Unrecognized response type; displaying content as text as shown in the picture above.
- is it good to set the asynctimeout with spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=-1 ?
- do you know please how i can solve the swaguuerUi issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Also about SwagguerUI: For big files (example: 74MB) The browser explodes and is not responding, then show the error: Could not render xt, see the console.

Please do you have an idea how to solve the swaguerUi issue?

Comment: @blaiso I updated the answer. Use this `ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename="+"yourfilename.pdf")
        .body(stream);` and replace the filename + extension then swagger-ui can understand it as a file download

Comment: Hi @phuongnq1995. Thanks. The issue here is about the file name. As I'm getting the file from another server, how can I extract the fileName and the file extension from the StreamingResponseBody? The goal is to show in swaggerUi the same file name stored in the server

Comment: @blaiso I dont think we can get file name from StreamingResponseBody, you can add the filename into header of response from the file server, and get it from the response of webclient.